# Is it better to use global variables and multiple js files or to use local variables and one long js file?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I am working on a project in Javascript, I always seem to end up with one "app.js" file that has more than a thousand lines of code. I try to break it up and put code in other js files (e.g. utility.js, routing.js), but the underlying issue is that the majority of the code often shares information through local variables, so it is easier to keep it in one js file.

I realize a counter-argument to this is to pass the variables as parameters in functions. However, this seems to get messy quickly.

One solution to this would be to use global variables, but I always hear this is a no-no in Javascript.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Is it okay to have js files with more than 1000 lines of code? I'm currently working a project and I'm up to 1600 lines.

Comment: This questions doesn't really fit here since it's primarily opinion-based. You should probably try to post this over on programmers.stackexchange.com as it's a bit more conceptual.

Comment: I think this may be one of the rare SO questions that would actually benefit from a migration to Programmers. Maybe it's not *quite* clear enough yet, but I think it could get there pretty easily.

Comment: @apsillers Best bet to get it there would be to edit it to make it clearer; one of our policies is not to migrate questions that would be closed for the same reason on another site.

Comment: @OP, I think the best way to clarify this question would be give specific code examples of why function-passing is awkward. this seems like the best way to do it, so it would be helpful if you can [edit] your question to contain a specific example that people could critique in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a development perspective, it's best to have individual files; then you usually combine (and minify) them into a single file (or small number of files) for live deployment.

Two suggestions for doing that:

1. Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) utilities, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)
2. A **single** global that you put properties on, rather than multiple globals

That second looks a bit like this:

widget.js:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.Widget = function() {
    // ...
};
```

spanner.js:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.Spanner = function() {
    // ...
};
```

...and so on.